# How to show reference level from lm output?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'd like to add a reference level to the final output of linear regression output lm().
For example:

```
levels(iris$Species)
"setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 

summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, iris))

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        4.78044    0.08308  57.543  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width        0.91690    0.19386   4.730 5.25e-06 ***
Speciesversicolor -0.06025    0.23041  -0.262    0.794    
Speciesvirginica  -0.05009    0.35823  -0.140    0.889
```

I'd like to have it like:

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        4.78044    0.08308  57.543  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width        0.91690    0.19386   4.730 5.25e-06 ***
Speciessetosa      
Speciesversicolor -0.06025    0.23041  -0.262    0.794    
Speciesvirginica  -0.05009    0.35823  -0.140    0.889
```

I've been looking for it a lot for a while but no clues yet. Any help would be highly appreciated.

@EDIT

Data for further expansion:

```
iris$Petal.Width <- as.factor(ifelse(iris$Petal.Width >1, "Big", "Small"))

levels(iris$Petal.Width)
"Big"   "Small"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic workflow you can work off of, is uses `dplyr` and `broom` to join your levels with your coefficients table. Right now it requires you know which variables are factors. You could change the `NA` to `""` if you prefer. It also organizes the output alphabetically which will not always put the reference group first. Let me know if you have any issues with scaling of this:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

iris <- datasets::iris

iris$Petal.Width <- factor(ifelse(iris$Petal.Width > 1, "Big", "Small"), levels = c("Small", "Big"))

reg_obj <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, iris)

factor_levels <- tibble(term = c(paste0("Species", levels(iris$Species)),
                                 paste0("Petal.Width", levels(iris$Petal.Width))))

full_join(tidy(reg_obj), factor_levels, by = "term") %>%
  arrange(term)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  term              estimate std.error statistic    p.value
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 (Intercept)          5.01     0.0709     70.6   1.03e-114
2 Petal.WidthBig       0.607    0.204       2.97  3.51e-  3
3 Petal.WidthSmall    NA       NA          NA    NA        
4 Speciessetosa       NA       NA          NA    NA  
5 Speciesversicolor    0.408    0.202       2.02  4.55e-  2
6 Speciesvirginica     0.975    0.228       4.28  3.33e-  5
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a really smooth solution. Right now I'm wondering how I can expand it, so it can handle more than one factor variable. I've attached extra data transformation to my post in order to obtain second factor for Iris dataset.

Comment: Hey @Tom, just udpated it for manually adding more levels. Is that what you were looking for? Let me know!

Comment: That's really nice! If it's not a problem i'd have one more question, if there's any possibility to add variables to "factor_levels" by using predefined vector/list of factor variables? Or I can specify them manually only?

Comment: Sure thing--instead of using `c()` with `paste0()` you could do something like this: `factor_list <- colnames(iris[sapply(iris, is.factor)])` and `unlist(lapply(factor_list, function(x) paste0(x, levels(iris[[x]]))))` to get the "term" column based on a vector of column names (of factor variables).

Comment: That's perfect. I've just build a loop for that, but that's definitely more elegant. Case closed, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output:

```
res <- capture.output(summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, data = iris)))
res[14:22] <- res[13:21]            
res[13] <- "Speciessetosa"
cat(res, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering if there's any more automated solution? As if the number of factor variables grows or we use different setups?

Comment: That would be possible. But since I don't condone this (or even understand the purpose) I won't spend the effort.

Comment: That's obvious. While I'll expand your solution, I'll post it here. Thank you once again for the help.